# Can not register Checkbox of NextUI to react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, nextui

I am coding a ReactJS project. I use react hook form to handle form submitting and NextUI (NU) as a UI library.

When I register a checkbox of NU like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitLogin)}>
 <Checkbox defaultSelected {...register('remember')}>
  <Text size={14}>Remember me</Text>
 </Checkbox>
</form>
```

Then I submit a form:

```
const onSubmitLogin = (form) => {
 console.log(form);
};
```

But the response I claimed from the console log is:

```
{
 email: "admin@gmail.asdsxc"
 password: "sadsad"
 remember: undefined
}
```

Note: I use raw input of HTML (no using NextUI for email and password input) and rigister => success. However, when I register for checkbox of NextUI, it log undefined value. How can I register for checkbox as well as input of NextUI to react-hook-form

Edit: More detail, when I check a checkbox, the console shoot an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

Comment: Since you are already spreading `register`, you could manually set `checked={getValues(name)}` and `onChange={(e) => setValue(name, e.target.checked)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Checkbox component from NextUI is a controlled component so when using react-hook-form you can wrap the `Checkbox` component in the `Controller` component from react-hook-form:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name='remember'
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <Checkbox defaultSelected onChange={onChange} isSelected={value}>
          <Text size={14}>Remember me</Text>
      </Checkbox>
  )}
/>
```